# VBA dynamic dates inside an API URL

Tags: vba, api, date

I have an API that I want to update dynamically so that the user can enter a start date and an end date on a spreadsheet and my macro will pull back data for that particular date range.

The issue I'm having is that within the API URL the StartDate and EndDate parameters must be in the format yyyy-mm-dd as a string.

I've tried `URL = "https:// ...&StartDate = Format(Date(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & EndDate=Format(Date(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&..."`  (the ... is for the things before and after the URL).

An example of the type of URL I'm looking at is:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:12345&startdate=2008-10-01&end-date=2008-10-31&metrics=ga:sessions,ga:bounces

I've also played around with adding in extra quotes within the URL string but I can't seem to get it to work.

I keep getting told that the dates aren't being recognised and therefore I can only get the code to run if I hardcode dates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a few issues in the code posted. The `&` is the concatenation operator in VBA. You need to enclose that in `""` to make sure you are returning the ampersand as a string, and *not joining* strings together.

I've added some sample code which hopefully illustrates the idea and get's you back up and running. The code should print out `True` if the `createdURL` and `testURL` are equal, or `False` if not.

**Code**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FormatExample()
    'This is the example provided
    Dim testURL As String
    testURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:12345&" & _
              "startdate=2008-10-01&end-date=2008-10-31&metrics=ga:sessions,ga:bounces"

    'This is a built string example
    Dim createdURL As String
    createdURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:12345" & _
                 "&startdate=" & Format(#10/1/2008#, "yyyy-mm-dd") & _
                 "&end-date=" & Format(#10/31/2008#, "yyyy-mm-dd") & _
                 "&metrics=ga:sessions,ga:bounces"

    'Print out if they are equal
    Debug.Print createdURL = testURL

End Sub
```